# Is there a way to annotate file/directory to be forcefully override on every rpm upgrade?

Tags: rpm

I have a java server application which is distributed and installed via rpm.

In my rpm spec files, is there a built-in way to annotate/set a specific directory to be **forcefully overridden and replaced** by a new package during every rpm upgrade, regardless if changes were made to that directory by the user?

I'd like to avoid brute scripting (i.e. rm -rf before upgrade)...

Comment: That's the normal behaviour for all files not marked as configuration files. Is something about that not working?

Comment: @EtanReisner - when I manually modified files in that directory, the rpm upgrade didn't override the entire content of that directory (though specific files within it were override).

Comment: You mean if you add other files to the directory rpm doesn't delete them for you? Yes, that's likely true (at least if your rpm only owns the files in the directory and not the directory itself but possibly even then). Why do you need the directory emptied of other files?

Comment: @EtanReisner - it's my server class files (in {TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/myApp/) and my rpm upgrade unpacks my *.war file there.

Comment: And what does the `%files` entry for that directory look like? Are you using `%dir`? Would it be reasonable to unpack the war file during `%install` and list the files in `%files` explicitly?